# jruby: java class accepts arguments in IRB but returns error when called from a class

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am using a class that accepts <strike>overridden methods</strike> *i meant optional argument signatures* (not sure if that matters in this case, but maybe)

when I call this from IRB it is working as expected, eg, it accepts the arguments

(filtering namespaces and passwords with [filtered] where needed to keep secret stuff secret and my company happy)

```
jruby-1.5.0 > require 'java'
 => true 

jruby-1.5.0 > Dir.glob('lib/java/*.jar').each{|jar| require jar}
 => ["lib/java/[filtered].jar", "lib/java/[filtered].jar", "lib/java/[filtered].jar"] 

jruby-1.5.0 > import "[filtered].His351n1"
 => Java::[filtered]::His351n1 

jruby-1.5.0 > broker = [filtered].Broker.new('[filtered]', '[filtered]')
 => #<Java::[filtered]::Broker:0x4c4936f3> 

jruby-1.5.0 > rpc = "[filtered]"
 => "[filtered]" 

jruby-1.5.0 > his = His351n1.new(broker, rpc)
 => #<Java::[filtered]::His351n1:0x7fb6a1c4>
```

and here is my spec and matching code

```
before(:each) do 
  @base = Legacy::Base.new
end

it "should create a valid his351n1 object" do
  his = @base.create_his351n1
  puts his.inpsect
end  

# from within Legacy::Base
def create_his351n1
  his = His351n1.new(build_broker, rpc)
end
```

and finally, the error which fails on the call to His351n1.new

```
1)
ArgumentError in 'Legacy::Base should create a valid his351n1 object'
wrong # of arguments(2 for 0)
```

To complicate things, on the irb, this is also apparently valid:

```
jruby-1.5.0 > his = His351n1.new
 => #<Java::[filtered]::His351n1:0x5ad3c69c>
```

Also, here are the overridden java methods

```
public His351n1() {
    super();
}

public His351n1(Broker broker) {
    this(broker, DEFAULT_SERVER);
}

public His351n1(BrokerService bs) {
    this(bs.getBroker(), bs.toString());
}

public His351n1(Broker broker, String serverAddr) {
    super(broker, serverAddr, "string", true);
}

public His351n1(final Broker broker, final String serverAddr, final String library)
{
    super(broker, serverAddr, library, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you have to require the whole namespace in the instantiation of the object aka:

`his = Java::[filtered_namesapce]::His351n1.new(build_broker, rpc)`